# SVM for multi-class in Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network, svm

I am trying to implement SVM for multiclass problems in Matlab. I know that there is an inbuilt code for SVM in matlab but I don't know how to use it. Need some help in getting started with Matlab SVM.

Comment: you need to be more specific.

Comment: Google "Matlab SVM" and read the documentation that you find there. Looks like Matlab's SVM is only for two-class problems.

Answer (score 0):

SVM classifies into two classes. If you want to create a multiclass SVM, you will have to hack it yourself. You could for instance do AdaBoost with SVMs as your "cheap classifiers", although they are not that cheap to train (contrary to decision trees or even decision stumps).

Speaking of AdaBoost, you'll probably end up using [ensemble methods](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/fitensemble.html) in matlab if you really don't want to program it yourself:

> For classification with three or more classes:
>
> - 'AdaBoostM2'
> - 'LPBoost' (requires an Optimization Toolbox license)
> - 'TotalBoost' (requires an Optimization Toolbox license)
> - 'RUSBoost'
> - 'Subspace'
> - 'Bag'

The ensemble toolbox is really simple and there's a ton of documentation on matlab's help pages. Basically you state your `X` and `Y`, the type of learner you want (for instance SVM) and the **ensemble method**, which is the method you want to use to combine the different weak learners. **AdaBoost** is one way, but you could also just do **Bagging** where the majority vote of all your weak learners counts.

So some questions you can answer here or at least ask yourself are: Why do you want to to multiclass SVM? Is it a homework assignment? Do you ***know*** how SVM and other machine learning alorithms work? Do you need help picking the right algorithm?

Comment: We want to compare a method we developed with SVM

Comment: There exists a multiclass SVM function in MATLAB: [`fitcecoc`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcecoc.html). Further it is a very simple task to train `k` one-vs-all binary SVMs for a `k`-class SVM.

Comment: I admit I forgot about `fitcecoc`... Keep in mind though that one-vs-all binary SVMs need a bit more work. What to do when multiple learners claim it's their class? What if none claim the data belongs to their class? Then you start defining weights for the individual learners based on their performance on a validation set. And before you know it you are doing something similar to adaboost :).